# how to subtract by 2% interest

Tags: java

- Customer c2 balance increase by amt - interest *  //This is the instruction.

I assigned Customer c2 to k2.

k2=(k2 + amt)-2

As you can see, I am increasing Customer c2 by the value of amt. The interest rate is 2%. I want to subtract by 2% but I don't know how to.

Comment: This question is of very poor quality.. Try editing this question so you can get accurate and specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : 
I assigned Customer c2 to k2.

k2=(k2 + amt)-(k2*0.02)

The above code will subtract 2 percent of k2  value from the  (k2+amt) value.

Answer (score -1):

k2=(k2+amt)

interest = k2*0.02

remaining amount = k2 - interest